# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function check()

Tags: php

I am getting this error for my php code. I am trying to create a function that will check the GET global for the 'page' variable and return the value. Here is my code.

```
<?php
include '../functions.php';
$title = "Links";
if(isset($_GET['page']))
   $title = check($_GET['page']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>This is some sample text</p>
```

Comment: So...where did you define your function? It's not shown here, and PHP is complaining that you haven't defined it.

Comment: Is `check()` defined in `functions.php` ?

Comment: I haven't defined the function yet because I am unsure of how to make a function that will check the get global for tpage variable and return the value

Comment: And anyway it's unclear what you want this function to do exactly? What checks do you want to make? The isset() call already checks that it exists. What else do you need, precisely? And what should it return (or do) if the checks fail?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the function check() before calling it.
Try adding:

```
function check($param) { //function code }
```

before calling it.